# How to determine M1000e CMC IP address from CLI of an installed blade?

Tags: drac, blade-server, blade-chassis

I have a Dell M1000e enclosure hosting 16 Dell M620 blade servers.
Each of the blade servers has it's own DRAC, accessible by its own IP.

In addition, the two CMCs in an active/passive configuration inside the Dell M1000e have a DRAC connection.

I can connect to the web interface on any of the blade DRACs, choose iDRAC Settings on the left tree, then click the Launch CMC Web interface button and it'll open a new browser pointing to the IP of the CMCs in the enclosure itself.

I've been writing scripts against the CLI of the DRAC, and I'd like to determine how the web interface for the blade DRAC gets the IP address information of its enclosure.  I've reviewed the CLI guide and the commands where I expect this information to be listed (get, getconfig, getssninfo, getsysinfo, others) don't seem to show it.

Ultimately, I need to know this information in a scriptable fashion so I can determine if fencing IPs defined in cluster configurations that should point to the CMCs are accurate.  It wouldn't be such a big deal if I had only this single enclosure, but there many of them, across many data centers.

Dell support says simply it's not supported and cannot be done, which I refuse to accept considering it does work via their web-interface.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

After much investigation, I was able to obtain this information using this command:

**racadm get System.ChassisInfo**

It seems to only work in iDRAC7 and newer.